# Proof Clarification: Restricting the range of a smooth map to a submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, differential-topology, submanifold

In Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds I've come across this proof.
[image]

[image]
It is unclear to me why we need to obtain this new chart $(U_0, \varphi)$, rather than taking any chart $(W, \gamma)$ of $N$ containing $p$, from the very beginning, say, and just show that $\tilde{\psi} \circ F \circ \gamma^{-1}$ is smooth as a map from $\gamma(W \cap V_0) $ to $\psi(W \cap V_0)$ ?

Comment: You need a chart $(Y, \gamma)$ of $N$ so that  $F (Y) \subset W$. If not $\tilde\psi \circ F\circ \gamma^{-1}$ is not even well-defined.